# Как обработать переменные, которые еще не объявлены?

Tags: php, вёрстка

В `php` коде переменные присваиваются ниже "по тексту". А по верстке мне нужно поместить результат обработки в таблицу выше. Можно ли как-то это победить?  Хочу посчитать `$totalKolvo` выше. Спасибо!

```
<div class="instrumental">
<table class='tg'>
<th colspan="4">Распределение по специализации</th>
<tr><td colspan="4"> 
<?
$totalKolvo=$kolvo100+$kolvo200+$kolvo300+$kolvo400+$kolvo500+$kolvo600+$kolvo700+$kolvo800+$kolvo900;

if ($kontingent!=$totalKolvo) {
    echo $totalKolvo . " Сумма по таблице не соответствует фильтрам";
};

?>

</td></tr>

<!-- 530202-->
<tr><td rowspan="<? echo $summ530202;?>"><? echo $jazz;?></td>

<!--<tr><td rowspan="<? echo $summ530205;?>"><? echo $folk;?></td>
<tr><td rowspan="<? echo $summ530207;?>"><? echo $theory;?></td>-->

<!-- ИЭО-->
<td rowspan="<? echo $quantity800/* Почему-то без +1 работает не правильно ??? */+1;?>"><? echo "ИЭО";?></td>
<?
for ($i=0; $i <$quantity800 ; $i++) { 
    echo "<tr><td> $arr800[$i]</td>";
$kolvo800=$actual_data->query("SELECT * FROM `$instr` WHERE instrument='$arr800[$i]' /*AND  Учесть фильтр!!! */");
$kolvo800 = mysqli_num_rows($kolvo800);
echo "<td><b> $kolvo800</b></td></tr>";
};
?>
```

Comment: Добавьте минимальный самодостаточный пример кода в ваш вопрос _(воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править")_

Comment: Добавил фрагмент

Comment: Можно прикрутить сюда буферизацию, только это костыльное решение. Правильно было бы производить необходимые вычисления _выше_ по тексту программы, и в html уже передавать полученные результаты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Невозможно поместить в таблицу результат до того, как он был получен. Измените программу так, чтобы чтобы результат получался до его использования, другого способа нет.

*Странный вопрос вообще-то.*

Comment: У меня в таблице в цикле выводятся ячейки и присваиваются переменные. А результат сложения мне хочется поместить в заголовок этой же таблицы. Вроде ничего странного не желаю

Comment: @musorgsky, Сначала считайте все значения, а потом выводите таблицу целиком. А как иначе-то? Ну подумайте сами, в самом деле - как можно вывести значение до того, как оно вычислено?

Comment: Я гуманитарий, поэтому мыслю несколько иначе. Я надеялся, что возможен некий режим работы интерпретатора, когда по окончанию прохода можно вернуться в определенный раздел по ссылке.

Comment: @musorgsky, вообще такие способы есть, например, обновлять ранее выведенные данные через AJAX. Но все это будет на порядок сложнее, чем просто переписать программу для вывода в один проход. И главное никакого смысла нет это городить.

Answer (score 0):

Что за библиотека работы с БД? Она должна уметь считать все данные в массив, за один вызов SQL, где ключем будет $arr800[$i]. И именно массив с ключем а не так как у вас сделано - в цикле многократно вызывается запрос. Сделать это до цикла, а в цикле просто читать массив.

Предлагаю использовать шаблонизатор, отделить код от представления. Например Smarty, изучите хотя бы часть документации, в том числе про циклы. Таким образом у вас будет два файла, один который производит вычисления и передает результаты в смарти. Второй файл это шаблон - выглядит как html с дополнительными тегами смарти

Comment: В чем недостаток множественного вызова запроса в цикле?

Comment: Медленно, один запрос намного быстрее будет.